# Como cargar una ruta dentro de otra en NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, nextjs

gracias de ante mano por tomarse tiempo y leer mi pregunta.

Estoy haciendo un backoffice para practicar REACT con NEXTJS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que al navegar por el menu vertical de la izquierda las distintas paginas se vayan cargando en el contenedor gris de la derecha.

A través del componente Link lo unico que puedo hacer es navegar de una ruta a otra pero no cargar rutas dentro de otra ruta que creo sería el caso. Leyendo la documentación de [NextJS Dynamyc Routes] [2](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) muestra como anidar rutas y pasar valores a través de ellas pero no dice nada o al menos yo no vi como cargar de manera dinámica rutas dentro de otras rutas.

Codigo fuente::

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import MenuVertical from '../../components/menus/menuVertical';
import MenuDerechoBo from '../../components/menus/MenuDerechoBo';

export default function GridTemplateAreas() {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        overflow: 'hidden',
        backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2',
        borderRadius: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        color: '#fff',
      }}
    >
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: 'grid',
          borderRadius:'0!important',
          gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(12, 1fr)',
          gap: 0,
          gridTemplateRows: 'auto',
          gridTemplateAreas: `"sidebar main main main main main main main main main main main"`,
        }}
      >
        <Box sx={{ 
          paddingX: 0,
          borderRadius: 0,
          gridArea: 'sidebar',
          bgcolor: '#3466FE'
        }}>

          <MenuVertical/>

        </Box>
        <Box sx={{
          paddingX: 0,
          borderRadius: 0,
          gridArea: 'main',
          bgcolor: 'secondary.main.gray',
        }}>
          <MenuDerechoBo />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**SOLUCIÓN HASTA EL MOMENTO**

No es lo que busco pero creo que es la manera mas fácil por ahora.
Hago un renderizado condicional basado en el valor de una variable de estado.
Aquí un ejemplo practico que hice a modo de demostración[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-kcphym?file=pages%2Findex.js).

En el caso de uso real, voy a usar un `Context.Provider`para pasar el valor de la variable de estado como global desde el menú vertical al Layout donde deben de renderizarse los componentes.

Si a alguien se le ocurre algo mas performante es bienvenida.

Gracias

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas son los  [Layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts)

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por responder. revisare la información

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberias de manejarlo con un layout, basicamente lo que tienes que tener es un componente Layout que engloba a tus paginas donde tengas tu menu lateral y en _app.js utilizarlo (en caso que lo necesites para toda la app, si lo necesitas para algunas pantallas debes hacer es utilizarlo en cada pantalla o utilizar una estrategia para escoger las pantallas que requieras en _app.js).
Te dejo un articulo donde explican mas a detalle [Layout patterns](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/)

```
// pages/dashboard.js
<MainLayout>
  <DashboardContainer />
</MainLayout>
```

Y en el componente MainLayout tu codigo debe ser similar a esto:

```
// components/sidenav.js
<Sidenav>
  {children}
<Sidenav />
```

Claro que falta agregar las props y estilos que necesites en tu aplicacion para estos componentes